# Can i create a promise which checks if variable is set in angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, q

I have a scope variable which is set after a few request and after some logic execution like this 
`$scope.record = {};`

`$scope.record.field = "custom_value";`

Now i have a different function which executes independently of this execution .

`function test(){ if($scope.record.field == 'some_value') { // do something }}`

The problem is that `if` condition should be checked only after $scope.record.field has a value .

I tried putting it in $q like this `$q.all($scope.record.field).then(func)` but it did not work .

I also tried using when `$q.when($scope.record.field).then(func)` but it still did not work.

Both the times i got undefined value .

I don't want to put any code in part where $scope.record.field is set which signifies the completion of assignment because i want to keep both parts separate and independent . Also both of them have access to the same scope .

How do i make sure some part of my code is executed only after `$scope.record.field` has a value ?

Comment: You can use like this `function test(){ if($scope.record!=undefined && $scope.record.field == 'some_value') { // do something }}`

Comment: create a service where you set the value, then create a promise in the service which is resolved once the value is set.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko i don't want to check whether the variable is set or not, but rather  i want certain code to be executed after the value is set and has some value .

Answer (score 2):

Snippet of possible implementation

```js
//one of the ways you could do that
'use strict';

(function() {

    function MyService($q, Util) {
       var trackThis;
       var deferred;
       var methods = {
          setValue(val){
            trackThis = val;
            if (deferred) deferred.resolve(val);
          },
          listenForValue(val){
            deferred = $q.defer();
            return deferred.promise;
          }
       }
       return methods;
    }

    angular.module('myApp')
        .factory('MyService', MyService);

})();
```

**EDIT**
Assume u have a controller as follows:

```js
'use strict';

(function() {

class MyController {
  constructor(MyService, AnotherService) {
 
    MyService.listenForValue().then(function(value){ 
//do whatever you want with the value
    });
    // Now introduce have another guy setting the value
    AnotherService.fetchValue(function(value){
       MyService.setValue(value); //this guys will resolve the previous promise
    });
  }
}

angular.module('myApp')
  .controller('MyController', MyController);

})();
```

**Note:** Add validation to prevent possible issues

**Remark:** Basically you create a service which allows u to share states among different active controllers, MyService allows u to create a promise, which can be resolved at any time by setting the value. Do note though that resolve can be invoked only once per promise

Comment: can you please provide a bit of explanation of what you have done or trying to achieve .

Comment: basically you create a service which allows u to share states among different active controllers, `MyService` allows u to create a promise, which can be resolved at any time by setting the value. Do note though that resolve can be invoked only once per promise

Comment: @AneeshKallarakkal assuming that the callback function of **MyService.listenForValue().then()** does the function of filling `$scope.record` with property **field** you can do the desired next operation right after the addition-of-property process like `AnotherService.fetchValue()`

Comment: @Yerken , i had already mentioned both the function share the same scope . So using a service is simply pointless and too much pain . Infact you could say that function should rather notify the other but i just want to keep both the functions independent of each other

Comment: @Aneesh then just call the function once the value has changed, you can use `$scope.$watch` for that purpose to track once the value has changed and call whatever you want. Promise would be simply redundant here

Comment: @Yerken , nice suggestion of using $watch . I am currently using a interval with indefinite time to execute the code which checks if the variable has a value and if value found it will execute the code and cancel the interval . Was concerned if i was doing it in a proper ways , but idea of using $watch seems to be better and more suited for this case .